# possible to change div height to 100% minus 100px with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I know almost nothing about JS so I just thought I would ask. I saw this in another thread:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function contentSize()
{
    document.getElementById('content').style.height=(window.availHeight-40)+"px";
}
onload=contentSize;
onresize=contentSize;
<script>
```

Looks straight forward but doesn't work...

Comment: Why did you tag your question `[jquery]`? You do not seem to be using it...

Comment: In case someone wanted to suggest a jQuery solution. Which someone did.

Answer (score 3):

If you do use jQuery, then http://api.jquery.com/height/

IE supplies this info differently than Chrome/FF/Safari so probably better if you *do* use the lib to help cover all the bases. You can use the height() function both to get the size of the window and set the height of your target content.

```
$('#mydiv').height( $(window).height() - 100 );
```

Comment: I wouldn't even know how to do that - but that's a start! thanks.